# How to pass a variable to {% url %} tag in django?

Tags: python, django, templates, url

I have 2 views: a and b they all render to one template T.
There are also a_2 and b_2 views. And T template should generate urls to the a_2 and b_2 views.

however I cannot use {% url %} because I cannot pass url name as a parametr.

I cannot generate the whole url in views because i should do it multiple times (one on a row in a table - so it could be hundreeds of links)

I do not want to write 2 exactly the same template. So the question is - how to avoid this ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is fixed in django 1.5.

In versions prior to 1.5 you need to use

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load url from future %}

{% url 'name_as_a_string' %}
{% url name_stored_in_variable %}
```

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/

> One deprecated feature worth noting is the shift to “new-style” url
>   tag. Prior to Django 1.3, syntax like {% url myview %} was interpreted
>   incorrectly (Django considered "myview" to be a literal name of a
>   view, not a template variable named myview). Django 1.3 and above
>   introduced the {% load url from future %} syntax to bring in the
>   corrected behavior where myview was seen as a variable.

Comment: i'l giv it a try. It would be great!

Comment: @KorniltsevAnatoly You don't need to update Django. Simply use `{% load url from future %} in your template. But note that this requires any URLs which don't quote strings to be changed to use quotes.

Comment: thanks for the note, however I updated to beta 2. It is not a production appplication so it does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in this case you can either use `{% if %}` tag and add some condition to it (and maybe some varianbles to the context) or write a custom url tag.

```
myapp
    templatetags
        __init__.py
        myapp_urls.py
```

myapp_urls.py

```
from django import template
from django.template import Context
from django.template.defaulttags import register

@register.tag(name="custom_url")
def render_map(parser, token):
    contents, url_name = token.split_contents()
    return CustomURLNode(url_name)

class CustomURLNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, url_name):
        self.url_name = template.Variable(url_name)

    def render(self, context):
        return reverse(url_name.resolve(context))
```

In template:

```
{% load myapp_urls %}

{% custom_url myvar %}
```

This is untested code and might contain bugs, but writing [custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags) should be a good solution.