# Django: How to use template variables along with url tag

Tags: django, django-templates, django-1.5

I am using Django 1.5.1

I am in need of passing the view name as a variable to my template.

Here is the relevant part of my view

```
return render(request, 'testcases/execute.html', {
        'table': table ,
        'submit_view': 'testcase_execute' ,
        "project": project})
```

And here is the relevant part of my template

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url submit_view project.slug %}">
                {% render_table table %}
                <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

As you can see, I am trying pass the view name ('testcase_execute') as a variable (submit_view)to the template.

But this way I am getting the error

**'url' requires a non-empty first argument. The syntax changed in Django 1.5, see the docs.**

I dont see whats wrong, as per this SO thread ([How to pass a variable to {% url %} tag in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14045221/how-to-pass-a-variable-to-url-tag-in-django)), if I need to use a variable with the url tag, I should not put quotes. There also exists other SO threads which tells the same thing.

I saw another SO thread ([Passing variable urlname to url tag in django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057318/passing-variable-urlname-to-url-tag-in-django-template)) which states this kind of thing (using a variable with url tag) isnt supported, I should be using django-reversetags for this.

Please throw some light on this- Is there an official (Django core ) way of doing this or should I go with django-reversetags

Comment: Have you double checked that `submit_view` is in your template context? What displays when you put `{{ submit_view }}` in your template?

Comment: Your looks fine. Reversetags is old, it was before this new url tag was created in django. Your error most likely because you somehow didnt pass submit_view  variable to your template

Comment: Found the problem, thanks for the help.As both of you suggested, submit_view was not reaching the template. 
The reason was, the aforementioned template code was from base template X,  and in the actual template used by the calling view , some other template B was being used as base.

So , for anybody who stumbles on this thread, there is no need to use django-reversetags anymore, Django (atleast 1.5 and upwards) is good enough to pass on view names as variables to url tags. thank you @Alasdair and Aldarund

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Prior to Django 1.3, syntax like `{% url myview %}` was interpreted
>   incorrectly […]
>
> […] you’ll need to change tags like `{% url myview %}` to `{% url "myview" %}`.
>   If you were using `{% load url from future %}` you can simply remove
>   that line under Django 1.5

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/releases/1.5/#overview

Answer (score 1):

`{% url 'submit_view' project.slug %}` i guess this can help you